# How do I serve two apps from different servers using the same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, heroku

I have a Rails app hosted on Heroku which servers generated pages for marketing/seo purposes. I have other content pages on another server, which are static pages. I want to keep them both on the same domain, to build seo goodness on that domain.

example:

domain.com/blah-blah-blah-something

should really load a page from heroku-server-name/blah-blah-blah-something but it LOOKS like it's from domain.com.

Possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can front the site with HAProxy and configure it for content switching.  To do this you have the frontend listen on some internal IP address that's mapped to your external IP.  The backends are your servers.  You setup access control lists to determine which backend to send to.  For example, this could be via some path name or file extension (such as .html goes to server A and .aspx goes to another).  In the end, the user has no idea they are on two separate servers, cause they only see the site being served on one domain name.

Note:
1) You won't be able to share sessions (which I'm sure you're already aware of).

2) HAProxy doesn't handle https, so if you need https then you'll have to have something to handle https termination, such as nginx or haproxy or stunnel.

Hope this is applicable, because I'm not familiar with heroku.

Answer (score 1):

The DNS record for the domain can only point to one IP address (and consequently server).  You could configure your heroku based application to render content from another server by effectively fetching the site and displaying it.

I've borrowed this code snippet from this link:

```
  def fetch_url(url)
    r = Net::HTTP.get_response( URI.parse( url ) )
    if r.is_a? Net::HTTPSuccess
      r.body
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  # use like this from your controller
  @snippet = fetch_url "http://www.oreilly.com/"

  # and in your page <%= @snippet %>
```

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1052-ruby-on-rails-how-does-one-render-html-from-another-web-server-to-a-ruby-on-rails-app/

There will likely be poor performance to any request like this as it will effectively take the time of two requests.